# TransientFailureException -- > While leasing tasks from pull queue

Tags: google-app-engine

We are using pull queues with backends in our scenario and our backend tries to lease tasks from our pull queue after some fixed intervals and in case there are no tasks , it does not do anything and in case there are any , those are processed . Yesterday we got this TransientFailureException in our system , which exactly is happening while my servlet is trying to lease task from pull queue . And the exception kept coming until we stopped our backend .

Our code snippet --

```
{
    Boolean leasedTaskFromFastQueue = true;
    Queue fastQueue = QueueFactory.getQueue("FastQueue");
    Queue slowQueue = QueueFactory.getQueue("SlowQueue");

    List<TaskHandle> tasks = fastQueue.leaseTasks(
        3600, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 1);

    TaskHandle taskHandle = null;

    if(tasks.size() > 0) {

        taskHandle = tasks.get(0);

    }
}
```

We aret getting error on the line where we lease task from fastQueue , which is a pull queue

```
<queue>
  <name>FastQueue</name>
  <mode>pull</mode>

</queue>
```

I am also pasting my error trace , in case that helps

```
com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.TransientFailureException:
    at           com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.QueueApiHelper.translateError(QueueApiHelper.java:79)
    at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.QueueApiHelper.translateError(QueueApiHelper.java:139)
    at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.QueueApiHelper.makeSyncCall(QueueApiHelper.java:53)
    at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.QueueImpl.leaseTasksInternal(QueueImpl.java:709)
    at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.QueueImpl.leaseTasks(QueueImpl.java:731)
    at com.implementhit.advancedsupport.server.queue.Backend.doGet(Backend.java:50)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.bitdual.appengine.tools.datastore.server.NamespaceFilter.doFilter(NamespaceFilter.java:96)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:102)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:249)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:135)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:477)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Answer (score 5):

It happend to us also, TransientFailureException is an internal error that as far as we could see had nothing to do with our code.  We ended up by automatically restarting the backend if 50 errors happened in a row.

Comment: Yea Even we could not find a reason behind it , we are making our backend code sleep for 5 mins once it encounters error and then start processing again , Can you please help me with the logic that you are using to restart your backend ?

Comment: @Smriti we used a dynamic backend, once the task queue start misbehaving we queue a task eta to 10 minutes from now that will "wakeup" the backend by calling a url with the backend as target.